# Apple News app scrolling buttons in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

[image: Apple News UINavigationBar]

How to implement such a navigation bar? I am aware of the title view but not aware of any subtitle view.

One way I can think of is setting UINavigationBar shadow image to nil and place collection view below the navigation bar. But that won't give me translucency of Navigation bar.

Is there a native way (which may have been introduced in iOS9) of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to make custom view and will have to use it as navigation bar. Hide the default navigation bar and use your custom view.

I wanted to make the nav.bar as shown in picture with the functionality like tab bar and i've made custom view for that purpose.

[image]

Comment: That would prevent me from having left and right navigation buttons.n which I don't want.

Comment: Can't you add buttons in that custom view?? You can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [PageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) or [PagingMenuController](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController) to do this easily.